# Seed ASP.NET Core database with Azure AD Authenticated user

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

In an ASP.NET Core Web App, if you're using a Individual User Accounts authentication and add Azure AD as external authentication provider is it possible to seed the app database with an Azure AD authenticated user?  And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your app has used 2 kinds of identity, one is azure ad and another maybe e.g. asp.net core identity. In your requirement, it **seems that the users from azure ad didn't exist in your user table of the database**.

In this scenario, you have to set up a **mapping relationship** between the azure ad users and users in your table so that azure ad users can get user data from your database. I mean that, when you asked this question, you may stored some azure ad users' information or you're about to store ad users' information in/to the database  but the columns in database may not have an user id which is correspond to ad user's id.

Then my ideas on your case is that, you can export all the users from azure ad, then batch insert them with a special flag into user table.